# I am trying to login and check whether the user exist or not but my execute scalar is returning null all the time which I don't know why?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to Login but I don't why the controller throws an error at `ExecuteScalar` of

> Object reference is not set to an instance of an object

If anyone can help me with this then please let me know, and any suggestion for making this better will be appreciated

Here is my ajax code:

```
$('#login').click(function (ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
    
            FieldValidation();
    
            var data = new Object();
            data.UserName = $('#username').val();
            data.UPassword = $('#userpass').val();
    
            if (data.UserName && data.UPassword) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'http://localhost:1089/api/Employee/IfExist',
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    data: JSON.stringify(data),
                    beforeSend: function () {
                        $("#dvRoomsLoader").show();
                    },
                    complete: function () {
                        $("#dvRoomsLoader").hide();
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data.Role = "Admin")
                            window.location = "../Admin/Index";
                        if (data.Role = "Employee")
                            window.location = "../Employee/Index";
                    },
                    error: function (ex) {
                        alert('Error' + ex.responseXML);
                        alert('Error' + ex.responseText);
                        alert('Error' + ex.responseJSON);
                        alert('Error' + ex.readyState);
                        alert('Error' + ex.statusText);
                    }
                });
            }
            return false;
        });
```

This is what I have written down in my stored procedure:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Employee 
WHERE UserName = @UserName AND pass = @pass

UPDATE Employee
SET IsActive = 1
WHERE UserName = @UserName AND pass = @pass
```

This is the method I have created in controller to be called on ajax hit:

```
[HttpPost]
public bool IfExist(Employee emp)
{
    var con = DB.getDatabaseConnection();

    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("sp_CheckUserIfExists", con);
    com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    #region If the User Exist then what to do Code Block

    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", emp.UserName);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", emp.UPassword);

    // com.ExecuteScalar();
    int UserExist = (int)com.ExecuteScalar();

    #endregion

    if (UserExist > 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Check parameters: `emp`,  `emp.UserName` and `emp.UPassword`. One of these is `null`.

Comment: If the user with that password *doesn't exist*, then the stored procedure returns `NULL` - which you're then trying to convert to `(int)` in your call to `ExecuteScalar` - without checking for `NULL`!

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: I *hope* as well you aren't storing plain text passwords in your database; the above looks like you might well be.

Comment: Don't use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Comment: @Larnu tell me how to not store my password as plain text in database, I am new to programming therefore I don't know much

Comment: You should be salting and hashing your passwords, @SyedMuhammadAousajaAli . A search of this methodology will a wealth of articles, tutorials, and documentation.

Comment: ...for example, [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4037/storing-passwords-in-a-secure-way-in-a-sql-server-database/) and [here](https://auth0.com/blog/adding-salt-to-hashing-a-better-way-to-store-passwords/), and some theoretical [here](https://bornsql.ca/blog/how-to-really-store-a-password-in-a-database/). Storing passwords in plain text is just begging to be the next data dump featured on [haveibeenpwned](https://haveibeenpwned.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ExecuteScalar is usually used for Select queries and it return the first column of  select. So change select to this

```
SELECT  Count(*) 
FROM Employee 
WHERE UserName = @UserName AND pass = @pass
....
```

but it is better to use just the second statement of your sp

```
UPDATE Employee
SET IsActive = 1
WHERE UserName = @UserName AND pass = @pass
```

and it will return number of affected rows, if you use executenonquery

```
 int rows= (int)com.ExecuteNonQuery();
 bool UserExist= rows >0;
```